# Spring boot unable to determine jdbc url from datasouce (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to load a MySQL database into a spring boot application but when I start the application I am getting those error messages:

`2018-07-17 13:46:31.426  WARN 2120 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource`

`org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: 'url' not set`

Although I have set the url property in `application.properties` : `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase`

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Edit: Here is my Main class:

```
package com.randomsoft.checkoff;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class CheckoffApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CheckoffApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: Is your file named as application.property or application.properties?

Comment: . properties. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Since you are disabling auto-configuration classes via '@EnableAutoConfiguration ' exclude attribute, you may try '@Configuration'instead of '@SpringBootApplication'

Comment: @Sri9911 that annotation was a suggestion so I can remove it. Using '@Configuration' instead of '@SpringBootApplication' messes with all my bean declarations,bean dependency injections...so it's not a viable option

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can start by removing:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

And also try to add all these *JDBC* properties,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: The error is gone. Thanks for your help. Let me just run an INSERT or something to make sure everything is ok and I'll mark your answer as the solution

Answer (score 5):

just try to append this line in your config class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Well that worked. I can't test it right now since I am getting a hibernate error but I guess is fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @adi_random hey,please mark this answer as accepted so that others know it's solved and do not waste time on it

Comment: Yeah,I wanted to first check everything works but I guess you are right

Comment: ...I am sorry. The error didn't go away. I think I've missed the stack trace when I said that it worked.

Comment: is there any change in error?? can you update ur question with your stack trace

Comment: also add the complete application.properties regarding datasource

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers recommend excluding **DataSourceAutoConfiguration**, and I agree with the approach, but what they don't tell is that besides the programmatic way via annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`, we also have the option of setting it via properties in the following manner which is useful when annotating an application class is not an option.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

You should name property file: `application.properties` or `application.yml`

Comment: Yeah,I didn't realise that the extension is .properties when I posted the question. My bad. I've updated the question and I've checked that my properties file is named correctly

Comment: @adi_random could you please post your entire class when located `public static void main(String args)` method?

Comment: I've added it now